# Static member inheritance and access through child member in Java

Tags: java, oop, static

I have the following case here:

```
  Room { price; }
        |
      ------
    /        \
standard    suite
```

I want to set price the of standard rooms in such a way that it remains static in all instances of `standard` and must not affect `suite`'s price and vice versa. I have tried keeping `price` in `Room` class `static` and accessing it via getter and setter in child classes but it doesn't work. I also am reluctant to make `price` members in each child class because I don't like that solution. Maybe there's another beautiful OOP solution to it.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question, I consider your requirement " i want to set price of standard room in such a way that it remains static in all objects of standard" a bad decision. You should reconsider that. Room-Prices can be individual even for the same physical room on the same day depending on who is booking and when (at least in most hotels).

Comment: You're asking for a beautiful OOP solution but using static limits those solutions.  *Why* does `price` need to be static?

Comment: @Fildor but sadly, that isnt required

Comment: @AndrewS because i want to make price of Standard Room same across all the Standard Room i.e its objects.

Comment: So you have no influence on that I guess.  Nonetheless I suggest keeping in mind this could change rather quickly.

Comment: I don't see why that means it has to be static.  The constructor could accept the price, it just happens to be the same price (for now) for all instances.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Having a separate `static` field in both the `Room` and `Suite` classes is the quickest/easiest solution.

```
            Room
     _________|_______
    /                 \
Standard               Suite
|                      |
 `static int price;     `static int price;
```

Alternatively, you could create a `static Map<Class<? extends Room>, Integer>` in the `Room` class which stores the base price of each `Room` type.

```
public class Room {
    private static Map<Class<? extends Room>, Integer> prices =
            new HashMap<>();

    public final int getRoomBasePrice() {
        // If a Room subclass does not have a specific base price, return
        // 1000 by default.
        return Room.prices.getOrDefault(this.getClass(), 1000);
    }

    /** Sets the base price for the specified Room type.
     */
    public final void setRoomBasePrice(int price) {
        Room.prices.put(this.getClass(), price);
    }
}
```

Using the above code will ensure the price stays constant across all instances of the class.

```
mySuite.setRoomBasePrice(2000);
(new Suite()).getRoomBasePrice(); // -> 2000
```

---

EDIT: After reconsideration, I realise that using `static` is not the correct method to solve the problem as it makes the code brittle and difficult to change.

The best method would be to have a separate `RoomPriceService` class, which provides a lookup for obtaining the price of a specific room type.

```
public class RoomPriceService {

    private Map<Class<? extends RoomType>, Integer> prices;

    public RoomPriceService(int defaultPrice) {
        this.prices = new HashMap();
    }

    public void setPriceOfRoomType(Room r, Integer price) {
        this.prices.set(r.getClass(), price);
    }

    public Integer getPriceOfRoomType(Room r) {
        // You can expand on this code by adding setters/getters for
        // setting and getting the default room price.
        return this.prices.getOrDefault(r.getClass(), 100);
    }

}
```

This way, you can have multiple `RoomPriceService` instances which can store prices for different circumstances (for example, you could have a `RoomPriceService` for each season, or a `RoomPriceService` for different sale promotions, etc).

Comment: The solution that you've provided is also possible to use without `static` variable. It is just "... **one** of the solutions to this" I'd rather say.

Comment: @Fildor, you are correct. I have added another, more object-oriented solution.

Comment: @GeorgeThomas Ok, that would be another. What I dislike about it: Is it the "Room" class' responsibility to know the room prices? Wouldn't that better be suited in a dedicated RoomPrice DataService or Lookup? And again: I strongly argue that room prices should not be static. In most etablissements I've stayed, room price will depend on room type, date of stay (season / big event in town...), duration of stay, date of reservation, booking platform, individual discounts ( milage cards, frequent guest, ...) ... just to name some.

Comment: @Fildor 9 months later, I have modified my answer based on your suggestions; would you mind taking a look? I reconsidered and realised that static was not the best method to solve the problem.